# Double series with WolframAlpha where the series are interdependent

Tags: sequences-and-series, wolfram-alpha

How can be written a double series with WolframAlpha where the series are interdependent like, for instance, the following ones? $$\sum_{j=1}^i \sum_{i=2}^n (i^2-j)$$

(I don't get, as expected, a result which depends only on $n$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like your answer to depend only on $n$, your sums may be in the wrong order.  Plugging in "Sum[i^2-j,{i,2,n},{j,1,i}]" to Wolfram Alpha gives $$ \sum_{i=2}^n \sum_{j=1}^i (i^2-j) = \frac{1}{12} n (n-1)(n+1)(3n+4). $$  If you have the sums set the other way, then $i$ is both a fixed number you're iterating to, as well as a variable you are using as an index.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to compute, as a function of $n$, the following sum: $\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=j+1}^n \min\{j-i,k-j\}$. I seems it still does not work...